# Multiple document.ready not working how to combine them to make a single document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(a) {
    a("body").scrollspy({
            target: ".bs-sidebar",
            offset: 0
        }),
        a(window).on("load", function() {
            a("body").scrollspy("refresh")
        }), setTimeout(function() {
            var b = a(".bs-sidebar");
            b.affix({
                offset: {
                    top: function() {
                        var a = b.offset().top,
                            c = parseInt(b.children(0).css("margin-top"), 10);
                        return this.top = a - c
                    },
                    bottom: function() {
                        return this.bottom = a(".bs-footer").outerHeight(!0)
                    }
                }
            })
        }, 100), a(".token-example-field").tokenfield(),
        a("#tokenfield-1").tokenfield({
            autocomplete: {
                source: outp,
                delay: 100
            },
            showAutocompleteOnFocus: !0,
            delimiter: [",", " ", "-", "_"]
        });
    var b = new Bloodhound({
        local: loutp,
        datumTokenizer: function(a) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(a.value)
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
    });
    b.initialize(), a("#tokenfield-typeahead").tokenfield({
        typeahead: [null, {
            source: b.ttAdapter()
        }]
    }), a("#tokenfield-1").on("tokenfield:createtoken",
        function(a) {
            var b = a.attrs.value.split("|");
            a.attrs.value = b[1] || b[0], a.attrs.label = b[1] ? b[0] + " (" + b[1] + ")" : b[0]
        }).on("tokenfield:createdtoken",
        function(b) {
            var c = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/,
                d = c.test(b.attrs.value);
            d || a(b.relatedTarget).addClass("invalid")
        }).on("tokenfield:edittoken",
        function(a) {
            if (a.attrs.label !== a.attrs.value) {
                var b = a.attrs.label.split(" (");
                a.attrs.value = b[0] + "|" + a.attrs.value
            }
        }).on("tokenfield:removedtoken",
        function(b) {
            if (b.attrs.length > 1) {
                var c = a.map(b.attrs, function(a) {
                    return a.value
                });
                alert(b.attrs.length + " tokens removed! Token values were: " + c.join(", "))
            } else alert("Token removed! Token value was: " + b.attrs.value)
        }).tokenfield()
});



jQuery(document).ready(function(a) {
    a("body").scrollspy({
            target: ".bs-sidebar",
            offset: 0
        }), a(window).on("load", function() {
            a("body").scrollspy("refresh")
        }), setTimeout(function() {
            var b = a(".bs-sidebar");
            b.affix({
                offset: {
                    top: function() {
                        var a = b.offset().top,
                            c = parseInt(b.children(0).css("margin-top"), 10);
                        return this.top = a - c
                    },
                    bottom: function() {
                        return this.bottom = a(".bs-footer").outerHeight(!0)
                    }
                }
            })
        }, 100),
        a(".token-example-field").tokenfield(), a("#tokenfield-3").tokenfield({
            autocomplete: {
                source: outp,
                delay: 100
            },
            showAutocompleteOnFocus: !0,
            delimiter: [",", " ", "-", "_"]
        });
    var b = new Bloodhound({
        local: loutp,
        datumTokenizer: function(a) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(a.value)
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
    });
    b.initialize(), a("#tokenfield-typeahead").tokenfield({
            typeahead: [null, {
                source: b.ttAdapter()
            }]
        }),
        a("#tokenfield-3").on("tokenfield:createtoken", function(a) {
            var b = a.attrs.value.split("|");
            a.attrs.value = b[1] || b[0], a.attrs.label = b[1] ? b[0] + " (" + b[1] + ")" : b[0]
        })
        .on("tokenfield:createdtoken", function(b) {
            var c = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/,
                d = c.test(b.attrs.value);
            d || a(b.relatedTarget).addClass("invalid")
        }).
    on("tokenfield:edittoken", function(a) {
        if (a.attrs.label !== a.attrs.value) {
            var b = a.attrs.label.split(" (");
            a.attrs.value = b[0] + "|" + a.attrs.value
        }
    }).
    on("tokenfield:removedtoken", function(b) {
        if (b.attrs.length > 1) {
            var c = a.map(b.attrs, function(a) {
                return a.value
            });
            alert(b.attrs.length + " tokens removed! Token values were: " + c.join(", "))
        } else alert("Token removed! Token value was: " + b.attrs.value)
    }).tokenfield()
});


jQuery(document).ready(function(a) {
    a("body").scrollspy({
        target: ".bs-sidebar",
        offset: 0
    }), a(window).on("load", function() {
        a("body").scrollspy("refresh")
    }), setTimeout(function() {
        var b = a(".bs-sidebar");
        b.affix({
            offset: {
                top: function() {
                    var a = b.offset().top,
                        c = parseInt(b.children(0).css("margin-top"), 10);
                    return this.top = a - c
                },
                bottom: function() {
                    return this.bottom = a(".bs-footer").outerHeight(!0)
                }
            }
        })
    }, 100), a(".token-example-field").tokenfield(), a("#tokenfield-4").tokenfield({
        autocomplete: {
            source: outp,
            delay: 100
        },
        showAutocompleteOnFocus: !0,
        delimiter: [",", " ", "-", "_"]
    });
    var b = new Bloodhound({
        local: loutp,
        datumTokenizer: function(a) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(a.value)
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
    });
    b.initialize(), a("#tokenfield-typeahead").tokenfield({
        typeahead: [null, {
            source: b.ttAdapter()
        }]
    }), a("#tokenfield-4").on("tokenfield:createtoken", function(a) {
        var b = a.attrs.value.split("|");
        a.attrs.value = b[1] || b[0], a.attrs.label = b[1] ? b[0] + " (" + b[1] + ")" : b[0]
    }).on("tokenfield:createdtoken", function(b) {
        var c = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/,
            d = c.test(b.attrs.value);
        d || a(b.relatedTarget).addClass("invalid")
    }).on("tokenfield:edittoken", function(a) {
        if (a.attrs.label !== a.attrs.value) {
            var b = a.attrs.label.split(" (");
            a.attrs.value = b[0] + "|" + a.attrs.value
        }
    }).on("tokenfield:removedtoken", function(b) {
        if (b.attrs.length > 1) {
            var c = a.map(b.attrs, function(a) {
                return a.value
            });
            alert(b.attrs.length + " tokens removed! Token values were: " + c.join(", "))
        } else alert("Token removed! Token value was: " + b.attrs.value)
    }).tokenfield()
});
```

Comment: please make it formatted so it can be readable..it is horrible currently.

Comment: Dont worry i resolve this horrible code hahaha

Answer (score 0):

According to docs I can assure you that multiple document.ready functions are working...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("test1!");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("test2!");
});
```

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/La7kLLfm/

Anyway if you are really asking "how to combine", o.O - Just put them all in one function body...

Sample:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("test1!");
    alert("test2!");
});
```

As you can see in first example, both document.ready() are called so you must have an probably runtime error in your script causing it to break, this can be a non existing variable or object because its initalized inside of an "if", a null object an invalid array index.. Your code is too long and complex to read without a decent example.

If you want any help by that, please provide the HTML output of your page that is required for it to work and maybe create a sample fiddle for it and explain us in short what its supposed to do and then we can check why its not doing what you expect it to do.

However your thread topic is answered and proven false.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT cname from country");

$outp = "[";
$loutp="[";
 while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp =$outp.''.$rs["cname"].'';
    if ($loutp != "[") {$loutp .= ",";}
    $loutp=$loutp.'{value:'.'"'.$rs["cname"].'"}';
}
 $outp .="]";
 $loutp.="]";
```

Comment: Yea, that is a start. However you should edit your thread instead of creating a reply for your own thread. And we are still missing the raw HTML (You can copy it from your browser's "source-code" window. This way we dont have to mess with understanding whats going on in your pretty hard to read PHP-code. And we are still missing an explanation what the heck its supposed to do, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all I have resolve my problem The jquery code is not executing complete because loutp is string but object required in place of string so i convert that using eval(loutp); now jquery executing completely and working fine now